# Retrieve Total working days (full,half,off day)

Tags: php, html, mysql

Evening everyone,

i am park, right now i am doing system for my small business.

## this is my code.

```
$query = "SELECT empid, count(t_status)FROM timesheet WHERE t_status = 'Full Day' group by empid";

$result = mysql_query($query)or die (mysql_error());

print "<table\">
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Total.Full</th>
<th>Total.Half</a></th>
<th>Totah.Off</a></th>
<th>Options</a></th>
</tr>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

print "<tr>";
print "<td>" . $row['empid']. "</td>";
print "<td>" . $row['count(t_status)']. "</td>";
print "<td>" . $row['HERE FOR HALF DAY TOTAL']. "</td>";
print "<td>" . $row['HERE FOR OFF DAY TOTAL']. "</td>";

print "</tr>";}
print "</table>";
```

==============================

so, how do i retrieve offdays and halfday total put display it in the next column of "full day".

Dont advise about "PDO" or "MYSQLI" because i will go through about that in the future.TQ.

Comment: I think you're after the psychic forum

Comment: `half` if `full/2` or `half` is `half * 0.5`

Comment: off-topic? i am sorry if my quiestion is not appropriate. newbie here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT empid, SUM(IF(t_status='Full Day',1,0)) as full_day,
                        SUM(IF(t_status='Half Day',1,0)) as half_day,
                        SUM(IF(t_status='Off Day',1,0))  as off_day
                        FROM timesheet GROUP BY empid";

$result = mysql_query($query)or die (mysql_error());

print "<table>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Total.Full</th>
<th>Total.Half</a></th>
<th>Totah.Off</a></th>
<th>Options</a></th>
</tr>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    print "<tr>";
    print "<td>" . $row['empid'].    "</td>";
    print "<td>" . $row['full_day']. "</td>";
    print "<td>" . $row['half_day']. "</td>";
    print "<td>" . $row['off_day'].  "</td>";
    print "</tr>";
}

print "</table>";
```

Comment: you have a typo, your alias is `full_day` but your key is `$row['fill_day']`

Comment: You are welcome
! Please rate an answer

Comment: i have no repution to rate it.sorry. but already click right sign. it that ok?